# custom authentication in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, authentication

What is the best way to set up authentication against a custom database of users, in ASP.NET? My current setup is not great, and I am sure that there is a better way to do authentication, but all I can find are some articles that are seven or eight years old. My current setup is as follows:

- Application uses the Windows username (via Windows Authentication), to work out whether a user is in a database of allowed users. This is done via a call to an Authenticate method in  Page_Load.
- If the user isn't in the allowed users, then the page redirects to a login screen.

The flaw with this method is that it calls:

```
Response.Redirect("~/login.aspx", false)
```

Which executes the entire body of the Page_load method. Is there a better way of doing authentication? Would something like custom Page classes, or HTTPModules do the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do your check earlier in the request, like in `OnInit`, or you could do something a little more robust, like implement your own membership provider: [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx) / [Video tutorial](http://www.asp.net/general/videos/how-do-i-create-a-custom-membership-provider)

Comment: This could be shoved into a base class that all pages could inherit from, couldn't it?

Comment: Yeah, using a base page class is a great idea for this type of functionality.

Comment: Excellent, that's exactly what I will do then. Seems so obvious now that I think about it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so this is basically how I done it. I wrote this class that inherits from `System.Web.UI.Page`. I override the `OnInit` event and this is where the authentication happens (looks up the Windows username against the database of users). If the user doesn't get authenticated, `isTerminating` gets set to true, and the `OnLoad` event only runs if `isTerminating` is `false`. I tried leaving a Response.Redirect with the second parameter set to false on its own, but this still ran all the subsequent page events. (even with a call to `HttpApplication.CompleteRequest()`)

```
public class BasePageClass : Page
{
    private bool isTerminating = false;

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        isTerminating = !AuthenticationManager.Authenticate();

        base.OnInit(e);
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!isTerminating)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I have no idea whether not running the OnLoad event is the best thing to do,  but it "seems" to work fine.